# Create WCF client for application/soap+msbin1 service

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

I'm trying to create a web service client for a C# application and the service AFAIK is only configured to use `application/soap+msbin1` encodings.  When I try to auto-generate the client via the Add Service Reference or via the `svcutil.exe` application, I get the following error:

> (415) Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
>   'application/soap+msbin1'

How can I instruct either utility to use `application/soap+msbin1`? Or, more generally, how can I create this client?

Just to clarify, I'm building a web application that is to be a client for a WCF web service.  I don't have access to the server config or code.

Comment: what does your web.config or app.config look like? can you post it in its entirety? maybe you need to remove the binaryMessageEncoding setting in the config file (if it is added there)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I should note this is a clean-slate application.

Comment: @ChrisThompson Is that the config of the server? There's no `<system.serviceModel>` section? Is it configured in the code?

Comment: @Szymon No it's for the client, I don't have access to the server config.

Comment: @ChrisThompson A bit hard to say but maybe the server is not configured to returned the metadata properly (or at all). Another way could be obtaining a WSDL file from the server provider. You can generate your proxy from a file, you don't need to connect to the server.

Comment: That web.config is not relevant and you should remove it from your post. The only thing is tells us is that there is no `<system.servicemodel>` section. Exactly when do you get the error? Are you getting it when you _call_ the service, or when you use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I agree, I only added it at the request of a commenter.  I get the error when I attempt to use "Add Service Reference"